# Pass media upload value to input field

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

I have created a `meta-box` that provides a upload function via the default media uploader from WordPress.

This works fine as long as I have one upload option.
But guess what? I want another one.

If I do this then the media box opens and I can select an image. The problem is that both `input`-fields are filled with the URL of the image.

I would like to be able to add multiple select options to upload images and preferably use one script.

Here is the script (output):

```
function dynamic_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamic_nonce' );
    $dsm = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    $post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
    $pn = $post['post_name'];
    $a = '_'.$pn.'_1';
    $b = '_'.$pn.'_2';
?>


<div class="image_large" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $dsm['dynamic-image'.$a.''][0] ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <p><strong>Image 1</strong></p>
    <p>
        <label for="dynamic-image" class="dynamic-row-title"><?php _e( 'Image 1', 'dynamic-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="dynamic-image<?php echo $a; ?>" class="dynamic-image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $dsm['dynamic-image'.$a.''] ) ) echo $dsm['dynamic-image'.$a.''][0]; ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="dynamic-image-button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Choose or Upload', 'dynamic-textdomain' )?>" />
    </p>
</div>
<div class="image_large" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $dsm['dynamic-image'.$b.''][0] ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <p><strong>Image 2</strong></p>
    <p>
        <label for="dynamic-image" class="dynamic-row-title"><?php _e( 'Image2', 'dynamic-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="dynamic-image<?php echo $b; ?>" class="dynamic-image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $dsm['dynamic-image'.$b.''] ) ) echo $dsm['dynamic-image'.$b.''][0]; ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="dynamic-image-button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Choose or Upload', 'dynamic-textdomain' )?>" />
    </p>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Here is the save function

```
function dynamic_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    $post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
    $pn = $post['post_name'];
    $a = '_'.$pn.'_1';
    $b = '_'.$pn.'_2';
    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'dynamic_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'dynamic_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed

    // Checks for input and saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'dynamic-image'.$a.'' ] ) ) { update_post_meta( $post_id, 'dynamic-image'.$a.'', $_POST[ 'dynamic-image'.$a.'' ] );}
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'dynamic-image'.$b.'' ] ) ) { update_post_meta( $post_id, 'dynamic-image'.$b.'', $_POST[ 'dynamic-image'.$b.'' ] );}

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_meta_save' );
```

And this is the function that calls the external `js` and supplies data

```
function dynamic_image_enqueue() {  global $typenow;
$post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
if( $typenow == 'page' ) {  wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_register_script( 'dynamic-box-image', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dynamic-box-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'dynamic-box-image', 'meta_image',  
                       array('title' => __( 'Choose or Upload', 'dynamic-textdomain' ),
                             'button' => __( 'Use this image', 'dynamic-textdomain' ),
                            ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamic-box-image' );   }}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_image_enqueue' );
    }
```

This is what the external `js` looks like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
var meta_image_frame;

// Runs when the image button is clicked.

$('.dynamic-image-button').click(function(e){
    // Prevents the default action from occuring.
    e.preventDefault();
    // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
    if ( meta_image_frame ) { meta_image_frame.open(); return;}
    // Sets up the media library frame
    meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({title: meta_image.title,button: { text:  meta_image.button },library: { type: 'image' }});  
    // Runs when an image is selected.
    meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){ var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('.dynamic-image').val(media_attachment.url);  });
    // Opens the media library frame.
    meta_image_frame.open();
});
});
```

Hope somebody can help me out!

------------ UPDATE ------------
I have tried giving the input button a unique value and pass this on to the external `.js`. Found out that I have to save the value to the database everytime I have selected an image. If I don't every input field wil have the value of the last image selected!

Still struggling with this one!

Comment: Have you tried adding "multiple: true" to the "wp.media({" ?

Comment: Wait. Wut.... Wow.. I'm having a mindblow right now. Is that possible? I'll check that out. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this to add as many image as you want with the botton click for example add logos or advertisements etc

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var mediaUploader;
        /* function to add partner logo */
    function display_ad( button,  title, btnTxt,  inputFieldId,  outputDivId,formClass, e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (mediaUploader) {
            mediaUploader.open();
            return;
        }
        mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame =wp.media({
            title: title,
            button:{
                text: btnTxt,
            },
            multiple:false,
        });
        mediaUploader.on('select',function(){
            attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();


            $( inputFieldId ).val(attachment.url);
            $( outputDivId ).css('background-image','url(' + attachment.url +')' );
            $(formClass).submit();
        });
        mediaUploader.open();
    }

    function remove_ad(inputFieldId, formClass,e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this logo?");
        if ( answer == true ) {
            $(inputFieldId).val('');
            $(formClass).submit();

        }
        return;
    }

    /** Different button clicks **/
    $('#logo-one').on('click',function(e){
            //display_ad( button,  title, btnTxt,  inputFieldId,  outputDivId, e)
            display_ad('#logo-one', 'Choose Logo One','Choose Logo','#sunshine-partner-one','#sunshine-partner-one-preview','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
        });
    $('#logo-two').on('click',function(e){
            display_ad('#logo-two', 'Choose Logo two','Choose Logo','#sunshine-partner-two','#sunshine-partner-two-preview','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
        });
    $('#logo-three').on('click',function(e){
            display_ad('#logo-three', 'Choose Logo Three','Choose Logo','#sunshine-partner-three','#sunshine-partner-three-preview','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
        });
    $('#logo-four').on('click',function(e){
            display_ad('#logo-four', 'Choose Logo Four','Choose Logo','#sunshine-partner-four','#sunshine-partner-four-preview','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
        });
    $('#logo-five').on('click',function(e){
            display_ad('#logo-five', 'Choose Logo Five','Choose Logo','#sunshine-partner-five','#sunshine-partner-five-preview','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
        });
    $('#logo-six').on('click',function(e){
            display_ad('#logo-six', 'Choose Logo Six','Choose Logo','#sunshine-partner-six','#sunshine-partner-six-preview','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
        });
    /*Romove button click*/
    $('#remove-logo-one').on('click',function(e){
        remove_ad('#sunshine-partner-one','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
    });
    $('#remove-logo-two').on('click',function(e){
        remove_ad('#sunshine-partner-two','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
    });
    $('#remove-logo-three').on('click',function(e){
        remove_ad('#sunshine-partner-three','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
    });
    $('#remove-logo-four').on('click',function(e){
        remove_ad('#sunshine-partner-four','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
    });
    $('#remove-logo-five').on('click',function(e){
        remove_ad('#sunshine-partner-five','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
    });
    $('#remove-logo-six').on('click',function(e){
        remove_ad('#sunshine-partner-six','.sunshine-admin-form',e);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is conclusive, but it's likely playing a role. You have 2 inputs, both with class `dynamic-image`:

```
<input type="text" name="dynamic-image<?php echo $a; ?>" class="dynamic-image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $dsm['dynamic-image'.$a.''] ) ) echo $dsm['dynamic-image'.$a.''][0]; ?>" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="dynamic-image<?php echo $b; ?>" class="dynamic-image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $dsm['dynamic-image'.$b.''] ) ) echo $dsm['dynamic-image'.$b.''][0]; ?>" />
```

In your JS script, you're then doing this:

```
meta_image_frame.on('select', function() { 
    var media_attachment = ...
    $('.dynamic-image').val(media_attachment.url);  
    ...
});
```

When you select a file in your media frame, the line `$('.dynamic-image').val(media_attachment.url);` will fill both inputs with the same attachment URL.

You could add a `data-` attribute to your upload buttons instead, like this:

```
<input type="button" ... data-target="dynamic-image<?php echo $a; ?>" />
```

then read it in your JS script, like this:

```
meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){ 
    var media_attachment = ... meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('[name="' + $( e.target ).attr( 'data-target' ) + '"]').val(media_attachment.url);  });
```

That should only update the relevant input, depending on which upload button you click.